# How can I install nuclide ide on Atom?

Tags: installation, arch-linux, ide, atom-editor, installation-package

I'm using an Arch Linux OS with KDE plasma desktop. I expect to work on some react native project using a better IDE. After some searching on internet, found the Nuclide IDE and I expected to install it.

For that, according to the official documentation of Nuclide,
first I tried to install the package using Atom package system as mentioned in [Nuclide docs quick install](https://nuclide.io/docs/editor/setup/#quick-install).

However I could not able to find out corresponding package from the package list. A screenshot of the package list:

[image]

Then, I tried this [stack-overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36195369/7483559) and all the commands are worked perfectly. However, when I open the Atom, always I get this error.

[image]

Even I go to the package list to verify package, couldn't able to find that option in there. Only I can see this.

[image: this]

I know Nuclide IDE is no longer maintain by Facebook. But nowhere I found that say it is no longer work. Is there a way to install Nuclide to my PC other than this? or is there a better IDE for react native application developments.
VS code is not a solution and it eats my memory so much. I needed some alternative for that.